# Set restrictions of two datepickers on same page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am trying to arrange some restrictions of two datepickers that are on the same page, but I don't have any clues at all what are my choices. So any hint if possible ?

```
var datepickerFrom = $("#stats-datepicker-from");

datepickerFrom.datepicker({
  showOtherMonths: true,
  selectOtherMonths: true,
  dateFormat: "d MM, yy",
  yearRange: "-1:+1",
  maxDate: new Date()
}).parent().find(".btn").on("click", function (e) {
  e && e.preventDefault();
  datepickerFrom.focus();
});

datepickerFrom.datepicker("setDate", "-1");
datepickerFrom.datepicker("widget").css({ "margin-left": -datepickerFrom.parent().find(".btn").outerWidth() });


var datepickerTo = $("#stats-datepicker-to");

datepickerTo.datepicker({
  showOtherMonths: true,
  selectOtherMonths: true,
  dateFormat: "d MM, yy",
  yearRange: "-1:+1",
  maxDate: new Date()
}).parent().find(".btn").on("click", function (e) {
  e && e.preventDefault();
  datepickerTo.focus();
});

datepickerTo.datepicker("setDate", "0");
datepickerTo.datepicker("widget").css({ "margin-left": -datepickerTo.parent().find(".btn").outerWidth() });
```

The only restriction set so far is that date can't be selected if it's after today, as per `maxDate: new Date()`.

What restrictions do I need exactly ? Well only common ones that are crossing my mind.

Example:

**1)** If date of `datepickerFrom` is "1 August, 2014", date of `datepickerTo` can't be selected as same date or past times of `datepickerFrom` (e.g. 8 July, 2014).

**2)** If user go and select at first `datepickerTo`, then opposite of **1)**

Is this even possible ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. However, have you considered using a plugin that already handles this for you? e.g. https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker

Comment: @colti - Woah, well that will solve every problem. Did not even think of searching for a plugin. Thanks for your answer, very good plugin!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change maxDate and minDate of datepicker when one of them is selected.

```
datepickerFrom.datepicker({
  showOtherMonths: true,
  selectOtherMonths: true,
  dateFormat: "d MM, yy",
  yearRange: "-1:+1",
  maxDate: new Date(),
  onSelect: function () {
      datepickerTo.datepicker('option', 'minDate', datepickerFrom.datepicker('getDate'));
  }
})

datepickerTo.datepicker({
  showOtherMonths: true,
  selectOtherMonths: true,
  dateFormat: "d MM, yy",
  yearRange: "-1:+1",
  maxDate: new Date(),
  onSelect: function () {
      datepickerFrom.datepicker('option', 'maxDate', datepickerTo.datepicker('getDate'));
  }
})
```

Comment: Very nice. I am trying the plugin that @colti suggested me. But this is a good reply to my question.